# Что делать если нет целевой переменой в датасете?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

есть три таблицы:

История активаций подписок
CID -- идентификатор клиента
SAP_ALLO_ID -- идентификатор активации подписки
PRID -- идентификатор тарифа
PRCID -- идентификатор услуги
CONNECTION_DATE -- дата подключения подписки
DISCONNECTION_DATE -- дата отключения подписки

Справочник тарифов
PRID -- идентификатор тарифа
PRODUCT_NAME -- название тарифа
PRCID -- идентификатор услуги
PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NAME -- название услуги
START_DATE -- дата начала возможности активировать тариф
END_DATE -- дата окончания возможности активировать тариф
FULL_PRICE -- полная стоимость тарифа
DURATION_PERIOD -- длительность тарифа в днях
IS_ACTION -- признак акционности (был ли тариф реализован для какой-то акции или специального предложения)

Справочник клиентов
CID -- идентификатор клиента
Gender -- пол (male/female)
regionName -- регион абонента
HouseTypeDescr -- тип дома
LocationTypeDescr -- тип населённого пункта
RegistrationYear -- год регистрации

В таблицах хранятся данные с 2009 года по 2022 года. Основаная задача найти вероятность подключения подписки снова, после того как она закончится. Я первый раз сталкиваюсь, что в датасете нет целевой переменной, из-за этого не могу продолжить делать задание. Подскажите пожалуйста, какие варианты я могу попробовать?

Answer (score 1):

Если в датасете нет целевой переменной, это скорее всего означает, что от вас ожидают, что вы сможете ее построить самостоятельно. Не очень разбирался в ваших данных, но вот например так:

- имеется- ли информация о том, что у одного и того-же клиента - было более двух подписок, причем время начала второй подписки больше, чем время окончания предыдущей. Если да - то это означает, что клиент возобновил подписку после того, как предыдущая закончилась.

Вот вам и целевая переменная.

Comment: Да, я тоже так думал, но дело в том, что есть сезонные смотрители, которые подключаются в определенное время года. Также есть люди, которые переподключались постоянно, но потом ушли. Еще у меня содержится три вида подписок, что тоже может играть определенный фактор.

Comment: Так у вас много чего еще может быть. Но вы задали конкретный вопрос - " найти вероятность подключения подписки снова, после того как она закончится" и ничего не сказали о других условиях. Вот на ваш вопрос я и ответил. А если нужны уточнения -  то формулируйте другой вопрос, и указывайте, а откуда вы можете получить информацию о "сезонных смотрителях", например. И как зависит то, что человек ПОТОМ ушел, на то продлевал он подписку или нет (о чем вы собственно спрашивали).

Comment: @SENSE Ну, вам там придётся подумать самостоятельно, как это всё учитывать. Например, человек отключился от подписки недавно, на этом месте у вас данные кончаются - вы по вашим данным не можете понять, подключится ли этот человек снова, значит не можете использовать данные этого человека для обучения модели. Ну и вам придётся вот это всё самостоятельно определить - какой период считается недавно, сколько нужно времени иметь в запасе от отключения до конца ваших данных, чтобы убедиться, что человек действительно не переподключился, а не просто у вас кончились тут данные.